# Running localhost webapp projects under domain name using fiddler2

Tags: tomcat, localhost, tomcat7, virtualhost, fiddler

I have a Tomcat server running on my local dev machine(running Windows8) & I use fiddler2 to assign an alias to `localhost` as my domain name (www.mydomainName.com), so my application webpages open in the browser like this:

```
 http://www.mydomainName.com/myAppName/welcome.html
```

instead of

```
 http://localhost:8080/myAppName/welcome.html
```

But I want to my webapp pages urls to omit 'myAppName' & be something like :

```
http://www.mydomainName.com/welcome.html
```

How could I configure to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly did you *assign an alias to localhost as my domain name (www.mydomainName.com*?

The simplest way to do what you want to do is to use FiddlerScript.

Inside Rules > Customize Rules > OnBeforeRequest, you'd write the following code:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl.HostnameIs("www.mydomainname.com"))
{
    // WARNING: REPLACE IS CASE-SENSITIVE!
    oSession.fullUrl = oSession.fullUrl.Replace("//www.mydomainname.com/myAppName/", "//localhost:8080/);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error on this line: `if (oSession.fullUrl.HostnameIs("www.mydomainname.com"))`. The compilation  error says **"Objects of type 'System.String' do not have such member"**.

Comment: Ok, I just fixed that replacing by : `if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.mydomainname.com"))` > but this solution actually changes the URL in the browser from `www.mydomainname.com` to `localhost:8080/myAppName/` which is not what I want. I just want to work under `www.mydomainname.com` but work as if it is just an alias for `localhost:8080/myAppName/`

Comment: Previously, To add an alias to localhost as my domain name, I had added to `Fiddler2> Tools> HOSTS...`  this line: 
`localhost:8080   www.openacads.com`

Comment: No, changing the request URL doesn't change what the browser sees.